# unable to add recycler view content into another activity like stack

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a list of the product in recycler view, it has price, name & quantity etc. I want to show individual list into another activity, actually I did, but I am not able to keep it safe, when I press back button and go to same activity, I find nothing, or I want recycler list like a stack onto another activity, please let me know, what should i do?

Comment: What you should do? Post your code!

Comment: add the code, screen shot or anythings you have tried.